# Angular class variable referenced inside subscribe result is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

listConstituents is DECLARED in the class, and INITIALIZED in ngOnInit.
getConstituents function's first line is a call to getChildren (which places an http request).

Inside the subscribe, the returned 'data' is fine, but listConstituents is undefined and is never set:

```
export class ...
constructor() {}

  listConstituents: Constituent[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // debugger shows this next line is correct:  Array(0) []
    this.listConstituents = new Array<Constituent>();
  }

  getConstituents() {
      this.dataService.getChildren(this.ProdID, 'Constituent').subscribe(
        data => {   **<-- return array of any**
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             let x = <Constituent>data[i];  <-- x cast to Constituent
             if ( x.Active ) {  <-- correctly accesses this part of Constituent
                this.listConstituents.push(x);   <-- ***this.listConstituents is undefined !***
              }
          }
        }
      etc.
```

Comment: How is `getConstituents()` called?

Comment: `...DECLARED in the class...` <= Keep in mind that the `OnInit` interface and implementation `ngOnInit` can only be applied to directives and components. Is this class a directive or a component? If not this method will never be called (by the angular framework anyways).

Comment: Also you make a call on `this.dataService` but this instance is not injected in your type (your constructor is empty). That could be another reason for failure.

Comment: It is called from another function in the same class and yes, this is a component,
My apologies, constructor does have private dataService: DataService, which does return the data.

Comment: Did you add `implements OnInit` to your class definition? When is `getConstituents` called and how is your "class" instantiated? Is it created as a part of a template, through the angular framework dynamically, or is there some custom code you wrote that creates an instance of this type? Answer can determine if `ngOnInit` will actually ever be called or not.

Comment: You really should create an [mcve], there is not enough here for someone to give you solid answer without making a lot of guesses / assumptions.

Comment: Try this `listConstituents: Constituent[] = [];` instead

Comment: I know ngOnInit is called. I put breakpoint on the new Array line and checked to see the result... see my comment in ngOnInit above.  Instantiated by routing.  
I will have to create a fully verifiable example that will run standalone I guess.  Sorry, I thought my debug information was enough.

Comment: BTW, with `let x = <Constituent>data[i];` you are not `casting` anything. You are just telling the compiler that the data should match your type.

Comment: You aren't using an arrow function. What you think `this` is differs from what the JavaScript engine thinks `this` is.

Comment: How is `getConstituents` called? If there is a chance that the caller is not correctly binding `this` the way it would be if it were called from a template (like `(click)=getConstituents()` in the html template) then you could define the function like this: `getConstituents = () => { .... your code here }` which will ensure that `this` is bound to the component the function is defined in.

Answer (score 1):

I guess getConstituents() gets called before onInit or otherwise executes before onInit somehow.

Declare member variable like this.

```
listConstituents: Constituent[] = new Array<Constituent>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your this is referred to get Children function. Assigning this reference to self and using self to access listConstituent of parent class can help.

```
getConstituents() { 
    let self = this;
    this.dataService.getChildren(this.ProdID, 'Constituent')
                    .subscribe( data => { **<-- return array of any** for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { let x = <Constituent>data[i]; <-- x cast to Constituent if ( x.Active ) { <-- correctly accesses this part of Constituent self.listConstituents.push(x); <-- ***this.listConstituents is undefined !*** } } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend what Karthik recommended (just instantiating it when you declare it).

Since you're using anonymous functions and concise methods, your `this` should be correct (I don't agree with what Ankur suggested)

I also wanted to give another way of how you're pushing the items onto the array:

```
this.dataService.getChildren(this.ProdID, 'Constituent').subscribe(
    (data: Array<Constituent>) => {
      this.listConstituents.push(...data.filter(x => x.Active));
    }
```